# How to solve "cv2.error: OpenCV(4.6.0) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'resize''"

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-segmentation, yolo

I am trying to make instance segmentation by using YOLOv7. In the segment.py file, I'm running into this problem.

```
def onImage():
    image = cv2.imread(opt.source)
    assert image is not None, 'Image Not Found ' + opt.source
    
    image **strong text**= cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    img_size = image.shape
    
    image_display = processFrame(image)
    
    image_display = cv2.resize((image_display), (img_size[1], img_size[0]))
    
    if not opt.nosave:
        cv2.imwrite(save_path, image_display)
        print("Output saved:", save_path)
        
    if opt.view_img:
        cv2.imshow("Result", image_display)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Results in this error:

```
File "C:\yolov7_seg\yolov7-mask\segment.py", line 103, in onImage
    image_display = cv2.resize((image_display), (img_size[1], img_size[0]))
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.6.0) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'resize'
> Overload resolution failed:
>  - src is not a numpy array, neither a scalar
>  - Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'src'
```

I'm using Python 3.9 64-bit and the latest version for all the packages. Thank you.

Comment: whatever `proccessFrame ` returns, it's not a valid numpy array

Comment: please show code for that

Comment: Typo error. What is this but no commas? image **strong text**